# SpriteBatch draw all

Tags: libgdx

I have a question regarding the Libgdx `SpriteBatch`:

When I call `SpriteBatch#draw()`, will Libgdx take care about the `Camera`s frustum or will it draw it, even if it is outside the frustum?

I was allready looking at the `SpriteBatch`s code, but I did not find anything, so I was wondering, if Libgdx does something internally.
Or do I have to implement frstum culling myself e.g. like this:

```
if(camera.frustum.boundsInFrustum(250, 32, 0, 100, 100 ,0)) {   
    tempEnemy.draw (batch); 
}
```

Where `tempEnemy` is a `Sprite`, (250,32) is it's center and (100,100) is his half size.

Comment: Sorry, but that was incomprehensible. You might need to try rewriting it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 It wasn't that hard to rewrite the question, but thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you are asking, whether Libgdxs `SpriteBatch` takes care about the `ViewFrustum` and just draws visible parts or if it just draws everything you tell him to draw.
If thats the question, the answer is, the `SpriteBatch` draws everything, ignoring the `ViewFrustum`. You have to take care about that yourself, or use Scene2D, which seems to do some [culling](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Group.html#setCullingArea-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle-).

Comment: @Tenfour04, the response, of  Springrbua, answered what I wanted to ask, sorry for my English, but I can not improve the question,

Comment: @AngelAngel Glad you could get help!

Comment: One suggestion, following this answer. I'm not sure if there is any payoff to culling individual sprites. Checking a sprite against the frustrum might be more expensive than simply drawing it in some cases. But you could group large areas of sprites and check them all at once with a single `boundsInFrustum` call.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks for the detail that you mention it, I'm working on that,

Comment: @Tenfour04 never thought about that, but you might be right. As much as i remeber the `SpriteBatch` has a buffer and only a call to `flush()`, `end()` or a full buffer will result in a draw call. Therefore, a bound check might be more expensive as culling won't even result in less draw calls. But as much as i remember in 3D programming with libgdx there is no buffer, so there culling makes a huge difference.

Comment: @Tenfour04 , Springrbua , in my case I think Tenfour04, is right, It is more efficient without cullig, I will try to describe what may be the reason, in my situation :

Answer (score 0):

this is a comment but to very long, I thought this would be the most comfortable way to read:

in my case I think Tenfour04, is right, It is more efficient without cullig, I will try to describe what may be the reason, in my situation :

-> It may not be less efficient by check of fustrum, but, by the operations you need to perform after

-> 1 in my case using an observer pattern, you see when the camera moves and notifies its current fustrum actors

-> 2 the actors have to look, if her are within range, having to call, getX, getw, ect, more instructions are added process

-> 3 if the actor is inside range, is added to, arraylist which now has the SpriteBatch with Renderable custom interface, more processing load, create the new arrayList if added or actors removed, by Array Class,

Maybe not the best implementation, and there things that could be improved, make a 2d fustrum not use arrayList ect, maybe all that would be more effcient, if you have many sprites in the game but for a few Sprite i think not.

My simple benchmark I did not, even if the fustrum will be used to cancel the update of the actors, because maybe if it would be efficient, for example, exclude many actors with animation, but these players do not move ect.in conclusion,

I think to a simple 2d game with few players is not efficiente in my case, I just wanted to comment, if someone helps

Thank Springrbua, noone and Tenfour04 for all

Note:
anyway, my simple game now has a rate of 60, 61 fps without using culling, a simple device, that's very cool haha